# Can I hookup a electric cooktop on 20 Amp breaker?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel

I am planning to buy a electric cooktop of 2 burners. Right now I have a connection of 20 amp breaker with 12/2 wire.

I am confused if both burner are opened at the same time. below are details and link.

- Amperage: 12.5 A
- Element #1 Wattage: 1800,750
- Element #2 Wattage: 1200

product more details:
https://www.homedepot.com/p/Magic-Chef-12-in-Radiant-Electric-Ceramic-Glass-Cooktop-in-Black-with-2-Elements-Including-Dual-Radiant-Element-MCSCTE12BG1/312733817?

Thanks

Comment: This is a 240 volt stove, so will need two hots plus ground at least(dual 20 amp breaker), probably a neutral also(so a 12/3 cable).  20 amp breaker will be enough for both elements.  Do not know if it needs neutral also, since that will require 12/3.  Might require a dedicated circuit(nothing else on it).

Comment: Don't take the marketing claims and try to turn it into fake nameplate data.  Just look at the real nameplate. What does it say?

Comment: Aside - is it a regional thing to call them burners, perhaps after gas cookers?    I'd call them elements personally.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You may want to either talk to the manufacturer or go look at an actual unit in Home Depot.

- The specs of 12.5A, 1800/750 + 1200 only make sense if this is a 240V unit. 1800 (largest of burner 1) + 1200 = 3000W, divided by 240V = 12.5A. So that would point to a 15A or 20A **240V** circuit.
- The Home Depot page says *Please note cooktop is 240-Volt* = **240V**
- The downloadable [specifications document](https://images.thdstatic.com/catalog/pdfImages/21/21ecb1f6-ec6d-4386-bd40-17b14c74ad83.pdf) says **120V**. It also says 1000W and 1600W elements. A 1600W element could work with a 20A 120V circuit, but not at the same time as a 1000W element, and a larger circuit is almost always 240V.
- The downloadable [installation guide](https://images.thdstatic.com/catalog/pdfImages/22/2241a0eb-3882-427d-8732-e62072d1d10c.pdf) includes:

  - Page 6: 240V/3000W, 120V/2600W
  - Page 7: MSCTE12BG1 (240V), MSCTE12BG2 (120V) - It looks like the Home Depot page is for the BG1 model. (And why they wouldn't make BG1 = **1**20 and BG2 = **2**40 is beyond me...)
  - Page 9: Use 8 gauge copper wire - That is typical for a 40A circuit.
  - Page 10: *A 3-wire or 4-wire, single phase, 120/240 volt, 60-Hz., AC only electrical supply is required on a separate,40-amp circuit fused on both sides of the line.* That repeats the 40A and seemingly requires 120/240 whether this is a 120V (obviously should only need 120 = 2 wires + ground) or 240V (should only need 240 = 2 wires + ground). My hunch is they boilerplate copied this from all of their larger cooktops/ovens/etc. where 40A 120/240 (120 for lights/clock/timer - none of that here; 240 for heating) is the normal requirement.
  - Page 12: 8 gauge copper wire
  - Pages 13 and 14: Typical 3/4 wire 120V/240V wiring diagrams

What I suspect is *really* going on:

- MSCTE12BG2 is 120V, 20A, and if you use both burners at the same time then you will have limited performance. **Do not get this one.**
- MSCTE12BG1 is 240V, 20A. That is the one Home Depot appears to be selling. Only needs a 2-wire + ground connection, 12 AWG wire or larger, *which you have*. However, you will need to switch from a single 20A breaker to a proper double-breaker to get 240V. Then mark the ends of the white wire in your cable with black or red tape to indicate it is being used (legitimately) as a second hot wire.
- All the references to 120V/240V, 8 gauge copper wire, 3-wire/4-wire connections are boilerplate copied from other manuals.

The real proof is in the underside picture on Home Depot:

[image: Magic Chef]

It shows black/red/green coming out of the metal whip, and it says 240V.

Comment: Gotta love it when manufacturers sell products that take "120/240V" but in reality, at 120V they just work poorly.  I have a hair dryer like that.

Comment: Yeah, you'll need the actual nameplate kW rating to determine the correct circuit sizing for the unit, something most cooktop/oven/range manufacturers can't be arsed to publish :/

Comment: That happened with the 4-engine A330 and 2-engine A340.  Somebody at Airbus said "wait a minute, let's switch those" lol.

Comment: Thanks@manassehkatz-Moving 2 Codidact .   So 12/2 romex won't work ?

Comment: Everything *credible* I have seen indicates this is a maximum 3,000W appliance on a 240V circuit = 12.5A. 12.5A x 1.25 = 15.625A (because of continuous operation rating), which means 240V 20A breaker and 12 AWG (or larger) wire. In other words, 12/2 Romex will work just fine, but you need to change it from "black to single breaker, white to neutral bar" to "black and white-remarked-as-black-or-red to double breaker".

Comment: Got it. Does it not need a neutral wire ?

Comment: No, it does not need a neutral wire. A *typical* cooktop/oven combination does need a neutral wire, even though there is no fundamental need for it (i.e., they could be designed easily without needing a neutral, but if the manufacturers can save $ 10 on a $ 1,000 appliance by using neutral then they do that) but for a simple cooktop (no lights, timer or fancy controls) there is really no reason for it - and in fact this particular cooktop *does not have a neutral wire* - the attached wiring (despite what the manual says) is two hots + ground.

Comment: Neutral is not "magic make things safer wire". That's *ground*. Neutral is "split things up to get 120V instead of (or in addition to) 240V". Which is simply unnecessary on a simple cooktop.

Comment: So I'll have just replace a single 20 amp breaker with a double 20 amp breaker. Also Is this all valid as per NEC ?

Comment: Yes, this should be valid per NEC. That being said, depending on NEC version and local adoption and local exceptions, etc. there *may* be a requirement that with a change in the circuit (as opposed to straight replacement) for AFCI and/or GFCI. Generally the requirements are not as strict for hardwired circuits as for plug-in receptacles, but there are a lot of variants so YMMV.